# List all the .exe or .iso under a directory in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to list out all the executables like .iso or .exe in a directory
My current code only shows *.iso. How can I make it generic to list all *.iso,*.exe,*.abc etc

```
export imageList=$(ls $sourceImageDir/*.iso)
```

Comment: Do you want to ***list*** them or save them in a variable? You sure, you want to save them in an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

with Bash:

export imageList=$(ls $sourceImageDir/*.{iso,exe,abc})

Comment: Can it be more generic?